# how to compile other programming languages using python?

Tags: python

I want to execute some other programming languages (e.g. C++ / java / kotlin) inside python and get the output.
is there any library or solution for this?
I dont want to create new programming language . I just want to compile codes.

Comment: Assuming that the compilers are installed on the target machine, call the compiler / makefile / maven / gradle with the required arguments and run the executable, both via `subprocess`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `run, PIPE` function from  `subprocess` library and `system` function from `os` library like this:

```
from os import system as sys
from subprocess import run, PIPE

# Example for c language with gcc compiler
sys('gcc ./something.c -o out')
out = run(["./out"], stdout=PIPE).stdout.decode("UTF-8")
print(out)
```

you can use run and system function in macos and linux, i think you can use it in windows too but i'm not sure